# How do I toggle 'draggable' for Google Maps GMarker object?

Tags: google-maps

I want to have draggable markers (already done), but I need to be able to turn off draggability in certain conditions.

Marker is created like this;

```
var Marker = new GMarker(center,{draggable:true});
```

...which works fine. But I can't figure out how to make it undraggable.

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
var myMarker = new GMarker(center,{draggable:true}); 
myMarker.disableDragging();
```

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMarker.disableDragging

Comment: That's it. Damn that was fast. Was searching for the wrong thing in API. Beautiful, thank you!